# Docker container started with docker compose can't access the port exposed by another container

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

I want the golang program to access the database.
However it seems to be no connection between the golang program and the sql database. Thus phpmyadmin works correctly.
How can i let golang service connect to the port 3306 ?
Docker compose
`

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.3
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "3306:3306"

    command: --init-file /data/application/init.sql
    volumes:
        - ./init.sql:/data/application/init.sql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: toor


  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      PMA_HOST: db
      PMA_USER: root
      PMA_PASSWORD: toor
    ports:
    - "8080:80"
    restart: always
    depends_on: 
    - db


  golang:
      restart: always
      build:
        context: servers
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      ports:
      - 10000:10000
      depends_on: 
      - db
```

`
Golang container

`panic: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: connect: connection refused api-golang-1      |`

I try to create a network, it didn't work as expected

Comment: You need to [`links:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) it.

Comment: `dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306` The database isn't running on `127.0.0.1`. Try `db` instead.

Comment: You don't seem to be giving any DB-related config to the Go app, surely it needs a connection string or the same data you give the admin panel to build one?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You should also use healthcheck in the docker-compose.yaml, to ensure that the database has been initialized before starting the go service.